# SQL multiple rows with same row names to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following data in SQL (nvarchar, nvarchar)

```
Name: Test Person 
Phone Number: 290831283
Fax Number: 192389182 
Email Address: test@test.com 
Name: Abacus Testing 
Phone Number: 901823908 
Fax Number: 9213989182 
Email Address: abacus@test.com
```

How can I format this data to be:

```
[Name] [Phone Number] [Fax Number] [Email Address]
Test Person 290831283 192389182 test@test.com 
Abacus Testing 901823908 9213989182 abacus@test.com
```

So basically setting the rows into matching column

I was hoping to use a Pivot table, but I only get the first row due to aggregation.

```
SELECT [Name], [Phone Number], [Fax Number], [Email Address]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
            ColumnName,
            Data
    FROM 
            TheData
) SRC
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Data)
  FOR ColumnName IN ([Name], [Phone Number], [Fax Number], [Email Address])
) PIV
```

I would prefer no CURSOR methods, any alternatives?

- Edit: added other fields available for use

The other fields available are Label Id for each entry. i.e Name=1, PhoneNumber=2, FaxNumber=3, EmailAddress=4

The common Id for each of the 4 entries is also available. i.e first 4 entries have id 1001, second 4 entries have id 1002

Comment: The problem is your data model. There seems to be no column that groups the first four rows as belonging to the same entity and the second four to a different entity. You *cannot* rely on any order they happen to be returned at the moment.

Comment: show how the data looks like in your table. not text.

Comment: If you have some kind of field that tells the order of your data, you could fetch a common number for rows in each of the groups based on that, and then used that in the pivot.

Comment: Forgot about the data model, that's the data I have to work with. The other two values available for each of those 4 entries are a common Id, and a Label Id. i.e Name is id 1, Phone Number is id 2, Fax Number is id 3, Email Address is id 4. For first 4 entries, you can say they have common id 1001, second 4 entries 1002.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following clarification in the comments you just need to add `CommonId` in to your source.

This is not an aggregated or spreading column so it will be used as a grouping column and you will get a row per distinct value of that.

```
SELECT [Name], [Phone Number], [Fax Number], [Email Address]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
            CommonId,
            ColumnName,
            Data
    FROM 
            TheData
) SRC
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Data)
  FOR ColumnName IN ([Name], [Phone Number], [Fax Number], [Email Address])
) PIV
```

Comment: Perfect, that was easy. I understand now what you mean by distinct row.